# All apps have "stopped unexpectedly" error

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

**ALL** the apps I run in emulator, including this downloaded from the Google App page will get the thisApp has stopped unexpectedly error.

http://developer.android.com/samples/BasicAccessibility/index.html

Any thoughts? Should I reinstall the Eclipse? Should I run on phone and not emulator?

Logcat:

```
03-13 10:44:34.158: D/AndroidRuntime(372): Shutting down VM
03-13 10:44:34.158: W/dalvikvm(372): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
03-13 10:44:34.198: E/AndroidRuntime(372): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-13 10:44:34.198: E/AndroidRuntime(372): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.basicaccessibility/com.example.android.basicaccessibility.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.android.basicaccessibility.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.android.basicaccessibility-2.apk]
03-13 10:44:34.198: E/AndroidRuntime(372): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1660)
03-13 10:44:34.198: E/AndroidRuntime(372): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
03-13 10:44:34.198: E/AndroidRuntime(372): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-13 10:44:34.198: E/AndroidRuntime(372): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
03-13 10:44:34.198: E/AndroidRuntime(372): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-13 10:44:34.198: E/AndroidRuntime(372): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
03-13 10:44:34.198: E/AndroidRuntime(372): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
03-13 10:44:34.198: E/AndroidRuntime(372): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 10:44:34.198: E/AndroidRuntime(372): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
03-13 10:44:34.198: E/AndroidRuntime(372): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
03-13 10:44:34.198: E/AndroidRuntime(372): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
03-13 10:44:34.198: E/AndroidRuntime(372): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-13 10:44:34.198: E/AndroidRuntime(372): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.android.basicaccessibility.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.android.basicaccessibility-2.apk]
03-13 10:44:34.198: E/AndroidRuntime(372): at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:251)
03-13 10:44:34.198: E/AndroidRuntime(372): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:548)
03-13 10:44:34.198: E/AndroidRuntime(372): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:508)
03-13 10:44:34.198: E/AndroidRuntime(372): at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1022)
03-13 10:44:34.198: E/AndroidRuntime(372): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
03-13 10:44:34.198: E/AndroidRuntime(372): ... 11 more*
```

sample_main.xml:

> `http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0`
>
>   
>   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
>   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
>   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or
>   implied. See the License for the specific language governing
>   permissions and limitations under the License.
>   -->
>
> ```
>         <!-- Notice the presence of nextFocusDown/nextFocusUp on the elements below. You can
>         also use nextFocusLeft/nextFocusRight. This tells the system in what order elements
>         should be navigated through. If not present, the system will make a guess based on
>         element location in the layout. -->
>         <TextView
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:text="Buttons"
>                 android:id="@+id/buttonsLabel"
>                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>                 android:nextFocusDown="@+id/composeButton"/>
>
>         <!-- This is a regular, text-based button. No contentDescription is needed, since the
>              text field sufficiently describes the action performed. -->
>         <Button
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:text="@string/composeButtonLabel"
>                 android:id="@+id/composeButton"
>                 android:layout_below="@+id/buttonsLabel"
>                 android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonsLabel"
>                 android:nextFocusUp="@+id/buttonsLabel"
>                 android:nextFocusDown="@+id/checkboxesLabel"
>                 />
>
>         <!-- The next two buttons are different types of image-based buttons. -->
>
>         <!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE (image_content_description) -->
>         <!-- Adding a contentDescription is needed for accessibility, since no text is present.
>         Since the contentDescription is read verbatim, you may want to be a bit more
>         descriptive than usual, such as adding "button" to the end of your description, if
>         appropriate. -->
>         <ImageButton
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:id="@+id/discardButton"
>                 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/composeButton"
>                 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/composeButton"
>                 android:src="@drawable/ic_action_discard"
>                 android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/composeButton"
>                 android:contentDescription="@string/discardButtonDescription"
>                 android:scaleType="fitCenter"
>                 android:nextFocusUp="@+id/buttonsLabel"
>                 android:nextFocusDown="@+id/checkboxesLabel"
>                 />
>         <!-- END_INCLUDE (image_content_description) -->
>
>         <ImageButton
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:id="@+id/infoButton"
>                 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/discardButton"
>                 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/discardButton"
>                 android:src="@drawable/ic_action_info"
>                 android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/discardButton"
>                 android:layout_alignRight="@+id/hyperspaceCheckbox"
>                 android:scaleType="fitCenter"
>                 android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
>                 android:padding="5dp"
>                 android:contentDescription="@string/infoButtonDescription"
>                 android:nextFocusUp="@+id/buttonsLabel"
>                 android:nextFocusDown="@+id/checkboxesLabel"
>         />
>
>         <TextView
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:text="@string/checkboxesLabel"
>                 android:id="@+id/checkboxesLabel"
>                 android:layout_below="@+id/composeButton"
>                 android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/composeButton"
>                 android:nextFocusUp="@+id/composeButton"
>                 android:nextFocusDown="@+id/jetpackCheckbox"
>                 />
>
>         <!-- Like a text-based button, checkboxes with text will often work correctly as-is.
>              If your checkboxes do not have a text attribute, you will need to add a
>              contentDescriptoin. -->
>         <CheckBox
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:text="@string/jetpackCheckboxLabel"
>                 android:id="@+id/jetpackCheckbox"
>                 android:layout_below="@+id/checkboxesLabel"
>                 android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkboxesLabel"
>                 android:checked="false"
>                 android:nextFocusUp="@+id/checkboxesLabel"
>                 android:nextFocusDown="@+id/hyperspaceCheckbox"
>                 />
>
>         <CheckBox
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:text="@string/hyperspaceCheckboxLabel"
>                 android:id="@+id/hyperspaceCheckbox"
>                 android:layout_below="@+id/jetpackCheckbox"
>                 android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/jetpackCheckbox"
>                 android:checked="false"
>                 android:nextFocusUp="@+id/jetpackCheckbox"
>                 android:nextFocusDown="@+id/imagesAndTextLabel"
>                 />
>
>         <TextView
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:text="@string/imagesAndTextLabel"
>                 android:id="@+id/imagesAndTextLabel"
>                 android:layout_below="@+id/hyperspaceCheckbox"
>                 android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hyperspaceCheckbox"
>                 android:nextFocusUp="@+id/hyperspaceCheckbox"
>                 android:nextFocusDown="@+id/partlyCloudImage"
>                 />
>
>         <!-- Images should have a contentDescription if they convey any meaningful
>              information. Images that are purely decorative may not need a contentDescription,
>              however. -->
>         <ImageView
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:id="@+id/partlyCloudyImage"
>                 android:layout_below="@+id/imagesAndTextLabel"
>                 android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imagesAndTextLabel"
>                 android:src="@drawable/partly_cloudy"
>                 android:contentDescription="@string/partlyCloudyDescription"
>                 android:layout_alignRight="@+id/discardButton"
>                 android:nextFocusUp="@+id/imagesAndTextLabel"
>                 android:nextFocusDown="@+id/customViewLabel"
>                 />
>
>         <!-- TextViews are typically self describing, so do not need extra modifications. -->
>         <TextView
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
>                 android:text="@string/temperature"
>                 android:textSize="60sp"
>                 android:id="@+id/temperatureText"
>                 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/partlyCloudyImage"
>                 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/partlyCloudyImage"
>                 android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/partlyCloudyImage"
>                 android:gravity="center_vertical"
>                 android:nextFocusUp="@+id/imagesAndTextLabel"
>                 android:nextFocusDown="@+id/customViewLabel"
>                 />
>
>         <TextView
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:text="@string/customViewLabel"
>                 android:id="@+id/customViewLabel"
>                 android:layout_below="@+id/partlyCloudyImage"
>                 android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/partlyCloudyImage"
>                 android:nextFocusUp="@+id/partlyCloudImage"
>                 android:nextFocusDown="@+id/dialView"
>                 />
>
>         <!-- Custom views require additonal code changes. See DialView.java for more
>              details. -->
>         <com.example.android.basicaccessibility.DialView
>                 android:layout_width="200dp"
>                 android:layout_height="200dp"
>                 android:id="@+id/dialView"
>                 android:layout_below="@+id/customViewLabel"
>                 android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/partlyCloudyImage"
>                 android:nextFocusUp="@+id/customViewLabel"
>                 />
>
>     </RelativeLayout>
> </ScrollView> </LinearLayout>
> ```

activity_main.xml:

> `http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0`
>
>   
>     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software 
>   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,  
>   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or
>   implied.   See the License for the specific language governing
>   permissions and   limitations under the License.   -->
>
> ```
> <LinearLayout style="@style/Widget.SampleMessageTile"
>               android:layout_width="match_parent"
>               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>               android:orientation="vertical">
>
>     <TextView style="@style/Widget.SampleMessage"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/horizontal_page_margin"
>         android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/horizontal_page_margin"
>         android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/vertical_page_margin"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/vertical_page_margin"
>         android:text="@string/intro_message" />
> </LinearLayout> </LinearLayout>
> ```

MainActivity.java:

> /*  * Copyright (C) 2013 The Android Open Source Project  *  *
>   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");  * you
>   may not use this file except in compliance with the License.  * You
>   may obtain a copy of the License at  *  *
>   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0  *  * Unless required by
>   applicable law or agreed to in writing, software  * distributed under
>   the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,  * WITHOUT WARRANTIES
>   OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.  * See the
>   License for the specific language governing permissions and  *
>   limitations under the License.  */
>
> package com.example.android.basicaccessibility;
>
> import android.app.Activity; import android.os.Bundle;
>
> /**  * Basic activity class.  *  *
>
> Responsible for rendering
>   layout, and displaying some toasts to give buttons feedback.  *
>   There's nothing terribly interesting in this class. All the
>   interesting stuff is in  * res/layout/activity_main.xml and {@link
>   DialView}.  */ public class MainActivity extends Activity {
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Standard onCreate() implementation. Sets R.layout.activity_main as the layout.
>  */
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.sample_main);
> } }
> ```

DialView.java:

> package com.example.android.basicaccessibility;
>
> import android.annotation.TargetApi; import android.content.Context;
>   import android.graphics.Canvas; import android.graphics.Color; import
>   android.graphics.Paint; import android.os.Build; import
>   android.util.AttributeSet; import android.view.View; import
>   android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;
>
> /**  * Custom view to demonstrate accessibility.  *  *
>
> This view
>   does not use any framework widgets, so does not get any accessibility
>   features  * automatically. Instead, we use {@link
>   android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent} to provide
>   accessibility hints to  * the OS.  *  *
>
> For example, if TalkBack is
>   enabled, users will be able to receive spoken feedback as they  *
>   interact with this view.  *  *
>
> More generally, this view renders a
>   multi-position "dial" that can be used to select a value  * between 1
>   and 4. Each time the dial is clicked, the next position will be
>   selected (modulo  * the maximum number of positions).  */ public class
>   DialView extends View {
>       private static int SELECTION_COUNT = 4;
>
> ```
> private static float FONT_SIZE = 40f;
> private float mWidth;
> private float mHeight;
> private float mWidthPadded;
> private float mHeightPadded;
> private Paint mTextPaint;
> private Paint mDialPaint;
> private float mRadius;
> private int mActiveSelection;
>
> /**
>  * Constructor that is called when inflating a view from XML. This is called
>  * when a view is being constructed from an XML file, supplying attributes
>  * that were specified in the XML file.
>  *
>  * <p>In our case, this constructor just calls init().
>  *
>  * @param context The Context the view is running in, through which it can
>  *                access the current theme, resources, etc.
>  * @param attrs   The attributes of the XML tag that is inflating the view.
>  * @see #View(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int)
>  */
> public DialView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
>     super(context, attrs);
>     init();
> }
>
> /**
>  * Helper method to initialize instance variables. Called by constructor.
>  */
> private void init() {
>     // Paint styles used for rendering are created here, rather than at render-time. This
>     // is a performance optimization, since onDraw() will get called frequently.
>     mTextPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
>     mTextPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
>     mTextPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
>     mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
>     mTextPaint.setTextSize(FONT_SIZE);
>
>     mDialPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
>     mDialPaint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
>
>     // Initialize current selection. This will store where the dial's "indicator" is pointing.
>     mActiveSelection = 0;
>
>     // Setup onClick listener for this view. Rotates between each of the different selection
>     // states on each click.
>     //
>     // Notice that we call sendAccessibilityEvent here. Some AccessibilityEvents are generated
>     // by the system. However, custom views will typically need to send events manually as the
>     // user interacts with the view. The type of event sent will vary, depending on the nature
>     // of the view and how the user interacts with it.
>     //
>     // In this case, we are sending TYPE_VIEW_SELECTED rather than TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED, because
>     // clicking on this view selects a new value.
>     //
>     // We will give our AccessibilityEvent further information about the state of the view in
>     // onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(), which will be called automatically by the system
>     // for each AccessibilityEvent.
>     setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             // Rotate selection to the next valid choice.
>             mActiveSelection = (mActiveSelection + 1) % SELECTION_COUNT;
>             // Send an AccessibilityEvent, since the user has interacted with the view.
>             sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_SELECTED);
>             // Redraw the entire view. (Inefficient, but this is sufficient for demonstration
>             // purposes.)
>             invalidate();
>         }
>     });
> }
>
> /**
>  * This is where a View should populate outgoing accessibility events with its text content.
>  * While this method is free to modify event attributes other than text content, doing so
>  * should normally be performed in
>  * {@link #onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent)}.
>  * <p/>
>  * <p>Note that the behavior of this method will typically vary, depending on the type of
>  * accessibility event is passed into it. The allowed values also very, and are documented
>  * in {@link android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent}.
>  * <p/>
>  * <p>Typically, this is where you'll describe the state of your custom view. You may also
>  * want to provide custom directions when the user has focused your view.
>  *
>  * @param event The accessibility event which to populate.
>  */
> // BEGIN_INCLUDE (on_populate_accessibility_event)
> @Override
> @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
> public void onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
>     super.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(event);
>
>     // Detect what type of accessibility event is being passed in.
>     int eventType = event.getEventType();
>
>     // Common case: The user has interacted with our view in some way. State may or may not
>     // have been changed. Read out the current status of the view.
>     //
>     // We also set some other metadata which is not used by TalkBack, but could be used by
>     // other TTS engines.
>     if (eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_SELECTED ||
>             eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED) {
>         event.getText().add("Mode selected: " + Integer.toString(mActiveSelection + 1) + ".");
>         event.setItemCount(SELECTION_COUNT);
>         event.setCurrentItemIndex(mActiveSelection);
>     }
>
>     // When a user first focuses on our view, we'll also read out some simple instructions to
>     // make it clear that this is an interactive element.
>     if (eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED) {
>         event.getText().add("Tap to change.");
>     }
> }
> // END_INCLUDE (on_populate_accessibility_event)
>
> /**
>  * This is called during layout when the size of this view has changed. If
>  * you were just added to the view hierarchy, you're called with the old
>  * values of 0.
>  *
>  * <p>This is where we determine the drawing bounds for our custom view.
>  *
>  * @param w    Current width of this view.
>  * @param h    Current height of this view.
>  * @param oldw Old width of this view.
>  * @param oldh Old height of this view.
>  */
> @Override
> protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
>     // Account for padding
>     float xPadding = (float) (getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight());
>     float yPadding = (float) (getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom());
>
>     // Compute available width/height
>     mWidth = w;
>     mHeight = h;
>     mWidthPadded = w - xPadding;
>     mHeightPadded = h - yPadding;
>     mRadius = (float) (Math.min(mWidth, mHeight) / 2 * 0.8);
> }
>
> /**
>  * Render view content.
>  *
>  * <p>We render an outer grey circle to serve as our "dial", and then render a smaller black
>  * circle to server as our indicator. The position for the indicator is determined based
>  * on mActiveSelection.
>  *
>  * @param canvas the canvas on which the background will be drawn
>  */
> @Override
> protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
>     super.onDraw(canvas);
>     // Draw dial
>     canvas.drawCircle(mWidth / 2, mHeight / 2, (float) mRadius, mDialPaint);
>
>     // Draw text labels
>     final float labelRadius = mRadius + 10;
>     for (int i = 0; i < SELECTION_COUNT; i++) {
>         float[] xyData = computeXYForPosition(i, labelRadius);
>         float x = xyData[0];
>         float y = xyData[1];
>         canvas.drawText(Integer.toString(i + 1), x, y, mTextPaint);
>     }
>
>     // Draw indicator mark
>     final float markerRadius = mRadius - 35;
>     float[] xyData = computeXYForPosition(mActiveSelection, markerRadius);
>     float x = xyData[0];
>     float y = xyData[1];
>     canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 20, mTextPaint);
> }
>
> /**
>  * Compute the X/Y-coordinates for a label or indicator, given the position number and radius
>  * where the label should be drawn.
>  *
>  * @param pos    Zero based position index
>  * @param radius Radius where label/indicator is to be drawn.
>  * @return 2-element array. Element 0 is X-coordinate, element 1 is Y-coordinate.
>  */
> private float[] computeXYForPosition(final int pos, final float radius) {
>     float[] result = new float[2];
>     Double startAngle = Math.PI * (9 / 8d);   // Angles are in radiansq
>     Double angle = startAngle + (pos * (Math.PI / 4));
>     result[0] = (float) (radius * Math.cos(angle)) + (mWidth / 2);
>     result[1] = (float) (radius * Math.sin(angle)) + (mHeight / 2);
>     return result;
> } }
> ```

MainActivity Manifest

> ```
> <uses-sdk
>     android:minSdkVersion="11"
>     android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
>
> <application
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
>     <activity
>         android:name=".MainActivity"
>         android:label="@string/app_name" >
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
> </application>
> ```

Comment: Have you updated anything?

Answer (score 0):

After 1 WHOLE week, I solved it. The solution is to comment out the fragments template that eclipse puts in. Man I am angry.

```
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first_screen, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

And this

```
        /**       
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
    **/
```

And changing XML file's tools:context which points to the Fragment.

This is really annoying and stupid. The default template that Eclipse creates, results in all these errors.